# How to convert string literals to strings?

Tags: python, string, string-literals

I want to convert a string literal like `r"r'\nasdf'"` to a string (`'\\nasdf'` in this case).

Another case: `r"'\nasdf'"` to `'\nasdf'`.
I hope you get it.

This is important, because I have a parser of python scripts, that wants to know the exact contents of a string literal.

Is `eval` a clever solution? The string literals are filtered before (with `tokenize`) and should not cause security liabilities. Aren't there any *nobler* solutions than evaluating a literal? A parser library maybe?

**Edit**: Added other examples, to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: that would be a 'raw' string, not a 'literal'

Comment: I think I didn't formulate my question right, I'm trying to do it right again. I meant string literals, not raw strings.

Comment: clear enough. and literal_eval is the nobler solution :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You want the [`ast` module](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html):

```
>>> import ast
>>> raw = r"r'\nasdf'"
>>> ast.literal_eval(raw)
'\\nasdf'
>>> raw = r"'\nasdf'"
>>> ast.literal_eval(raw)
'\nasdf'
```

This is a safe method for evaluating/parsing strings that contain Python source code (unlike `eval()`).

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there are:

```
>>> s = r'\nasdf'
>>> s.decode('string-escape')
'\nasdf'
```

Comment: Sorry, my question was not too clear (I edited). This is a raw string to string conversion, not a string literal to string conversion.