# Convert string literal to string or raise error, Python

Tags: python, parsing, python-2.x

I have a string, which may or may not contain a syntactically valid Python string literal.  If it does, I want to convert it to the string it represents, otherwise I want to raise an error.  Is there a *better way* to accomplish this than

```
# 'x' contains the putative string literal
s = ast.literal_eval(x)
if not isinstance(s, basestring):
    raise ValueError("not a valid string literal: " + x)
```

In particular, because of the origin of this string, it could potentially contain the `repr` of a complex object, and I don't want to waste time parsing that and then throwing it away.

Another way to put it is that I want the behavior of `float` or `int` when applied to a string, only for, well, strings.

[Note: The existing question [Python convert string literals to strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494789/python-convert-string-literals-to-strings) recommends `ast.literal_eval`, but that is what I am hoping to be able to beat.]

Comment: You can short-circuit it slightly by `if x[0]==x[-1] and x[0] in '\'"'` but I think that's probably as good as it gets

Answer (score 2):

I think that you could use a regular expression. A syntactically valid Python string is:

- `''` on one line containing anything except `'` preceeded by an even number of `\`
- `""` on one line containing anything except `\n` `"` preceeded by an even number of `\`
- `""" """` containing anything except `"""` preceeded by an even number of `\`
- `''' '''` containing anything except `'''` preceeded by an even number of `\`

Theoretically you should be able to write a regex to match one of those, and I think that should work.

It might not be any faster or better than `ast.literal_eval`, even with a complex object.

Now that I think about it, you could simply do:

```
if x.lstrip().startswith(("'", '"')): #Might be a string
```

as a pre-filter.

Comment: @JonClements, that's why I updated my answer to say that it probably wouldn't be any faster than `ast.literal_eval` ;)

Comment: @JonClements, ah yes, I don't get to work with Python nearly enough - I keep forgetting that you can pass a collection that way.

Comment: That's what I get for trying to edit right before I leave for home ;)