# How to literally convert string to bytes?

Tags: python, byte

I have this following key in my app, which although the prefix, it is saved as a string and not bytes (`<class 'str'>`).

```
b'-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\nMBgCEQCc5QP2pLttRTltj9QFdn1DAgMBAAE=\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n'
```

I try to convert is into bytes string, using bytes() or .encode, but both returns the following format which is not the same:

```
b"b'-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\\nMBgCEQCc5QP2pLttRTltj9QFdn1DAgMBAAE=\\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\\n'" <class 'bytes'>
```

Any clue on how to tell my program to just take this string as it is and read it as bytes?

Comment: The first sample is a bytes object already, could you clarify what you want to do?

Comment: @Passerby Hey, although the prefix, it is saved as a string and not bytes, when I use the type() function I get `(<class 'str'>)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python convert string literals to strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494789/python-convert-string-literals-to-strings) While the question is about parsing string literals as strings, the answers apply to parsing any sort of Python literal. In your case, you want to parse a string containing a bytes literals as bytes, so `ast.literal_eval` will do the trick.

Comment: Show us some sample code, not just the string.

Comment: Does a function taking a parameter that is typed as 'bytes' throw an error if you give it a 'str'?  Then it shouldn't matter which function it is you had to typecast it and it wasn't anything to do with literals.

Comment: The answer has to be how to typecast it unless you found a duplicate.  @Brian did not.

Comment: If you actually have a string that contains the `b'...'` stuff, then my advice would be: Avoid being in that situation in the first place! Find out what caused it, and fix *that*!

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `bytes(string, enc)` function.

Assuming that you're using utf-8 this should work with python3.

```
_string = "Some String"
_string_as_bytes = bytes(_string, 'utf-8')
```

EDIT:
But what you have is the console output and that is displayed as `b'Some String'`, but you had that stored as if you had run `_string = "b'Some String'"` so you needed a substring of the original that trimmed away `b'` and the trailing `'`.

so if you `_string = _string[2:len(_string)-1]` then you get the substring with the delimiter removed.  Console displays it as `'Some String'` and then you can make the call to `bytes(...)` as above.

Comment: from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-string-to-bytes/#:~:text=String%20can%20be%20converted%20to%20bytes%20using%20the,function%20for%20converting%20the%20string%20to%20specified%20encoding.

Comment: from https://www.journaldev.com/23774/python-string-substring#:~:text=%20Python%20String%20Substring%20%201%20Create%20a,of%20occurrences%20of%20a%20substring%20in...%20More%20