# splitlines() of lldb SBValue.GetSummary() result doesn't work?

Tags: python, lldb

I have a program that supplies context dependent information that I'd like to display in lldb.  For illustration purposes, imagine that program is as simple as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char * get_perform_stack() {
   return "CARP-AND-RETURN-IF-VSAM-ERROR\nMAIN\n";
}

int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

In an lldb session, after breaking in main, I can run:

```
(lldb) expression -l c -- (char *)get_perform_stack()
(char *) $2 = 0x00000000004005e8 "CARP-AND-RETURN-IF-VSAM-ERROR\nMAIN\n"
```

I'd like to make an lldb python script that calls this function, but displays the results, in this case, as two lines:

```
CARP-AND-RETURN-IF-VSAM-ERROR
MAIN
```

Given such a string with newlines in it, I can tokenize it in pure python with something like:

```
stack = "CARP-AND-RETURN-IF-VSAM-ERROR\nMAIN\n"

print(type(stack))
print(stack)

a = stack.splitlines()
for f in a:
    print(f)
```

which gives:

```
# python3 ./sp
<class 'str'>
CARP-AND-RETURN-IF-VSAM-ERROR
MAIN

CARP-AND-RETURN-IF-VSAM-ERROR
MAIN
```

I'm also able to obtain this result using lldb python code, but if I put in the same sort of tokenizing code, it doesn't work within my lldb python script.  Example:

```
import lldb

# (lldb) command script import ~/lldb/cobbt.py
# (lldb) script cobbt.main()

def main() -> None:
    debugger = lldb.target.GetDebugger()

    exprOptions = lldb.SBExpressionOptions()
    c = lldb.SBLanguageRuntime_GetLanguageTypeFromString("c")
    exprOptions.SetLanguage( c )

    result = lldb.target.EvaluateExpression("(char *)get_perform_stack()", exprOptions)
    print(type(result))
    
    s = result.GetSummary()
    print(type(s))
    print(s)
    stack = s.splitlines()
    for f in stack:
        print(f)
```

The splitlines() doesn't seem to do anything, and I get a single element back:

```
(lldb) command script import ~/lldb/cobbt.py                                                                                                                       
(lldb) script cobbt.main()
<class 'lldb.SBValue'>
<class 'str'>
"CARP-AND-RETURN-IF-VSAM-ERROR\nMAIN\n"
"CARP-AND-RETURN-IF-VSAM-ERROR\nMAIN\n"
(lldb)
```

In both cases, python seems to think that the result that I'm trying to tokenize is a "class str", but the behaviour within lldb's python interpreter is different than that of standalone python, and I'm not sure what that difference is, or how to fix my code to display the results separately?

For reference: I'm running lldb version 14.0.6, built with python3 scripting support.

Comment: It seems like `s` contains a backslash and an 'n', not a LF character.

Comment: You are probably looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494789/how-to-convert-string-literals-to-strings

Comment: The summary for `char *` is designed to display the string as you typed it in your code.  The string you typed had a backslash and then an "n", so that's what the summary should have.

Answer (score 0):

The lldb result isn't a '\n' character, but two characters: '\', 'n'.  I can split with something like this instead:

```
stack = s.split('\\n')
i = 0
for f in stack:
    print("{}.{}".format(i,f))
    i += 1
```

This needs some fine tuning, since I have to strip out the " characters and last line too, as it gives me:

```
0."CARP-AND-RETURN-IF-VSAM-ERROR
1.MAIN
2."
```

but that's probably not too hard.